# Recursive call inside map

Tags: haskell

Having the following function:

```
between :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
between i [] = [[i]]
between i r@(x:xs) = [[i]++r] ++ map f (between i xs)
                     where f = (\n->[x] ++ n)
```

And the result of `between 0 [1,2]` being:

```
[[0,1,2],[1,0,2],[1,2,0]]
```

How is this possible? I am able to understand the two first cases:

- `[0,1,2]` because of `[[0]++[1,2]]`
- `[1,0,2]` because `map f [[0]++[2]]`(where x is 1)

**Is the map recursing as well?** And keeping a reference to all initial `x` so it then just contacts all? In my head the final result would be something like:

```
[[0,1,2],[1,0,2],[2,0]]
```

PS: With "map recursing" as well is something a long the lines:

```
\n -> [1] + n
   \n ->[2] + n
      \n ->[3] + n
         \n ->[m] + n
```

Comment: The map is applied to the entire result of the recursion, which is `[[0,2], [2,0]]`.

Comment: Side note: `[i]++r` can be simplified to `i:r`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's fix this function to use cons (`:`) rather than `++`, since the former is more efficient and idiomatic when prepending an element to the front of a list, and it can also simplify the function a fair amount:

```
between i [] = [[i]]
between i r@(x:xs) = (i : r) : map (x:) (between i xs)
```

This will be easier to use to walk through the steps:

```
between 0 [1, 2] =
    (0 : [1, 2]) : map (1:) (between 0 [2])
    [0, 1, 2] : map (1:) ((0 : [2]) : map (2:) (between 0 []))
    [0, 1, 2] : map (1:) ([0, 2] : map (2:) [[0]])
    [0, 1, 2] : map (1:) ([0, 2] : [[2, 0]])
    [0, 1, 2] : map (1:) [[0, 2], [2, 0]]
    [0, 1, 2] : [1:[0, 2], 1:[2, 0]]
    [0, 1, 2] : [[1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0]]
    [[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0]]
```

So by equational reasoning, we can work out the steps GHC took to arrive at this answer.

Comment: thanks @bheklilr I was missing the idea of `map (1:) ( applied to everything else )`

Answer (score 1):

But remember, between returns the result for the whole tail

```
between 0 [2]
```

gives

```
[[0, 2], [2, 0]]
```

applying `f` prepends `1` to everything

```
[[1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0]]
```

Finally, we add the `[[i]++r]` (which would be better written as `[i:r]`)

```
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0]]
```